# What should be structure of Vue component? in which order functions should be added?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there any systematic structure for Vue component? In which order computed , methods, components, mounted watch etc should be written?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**
For `component` I mostly prefer putting `script` tags before `html` tags. As the idea that we mostly use to play with `js` so I feel itchy to move down always in the page. Else make your layout as per your preference

As per Vue official style guide -

Component/instance options should be ordered consistently.

This is the default order we recommend for component options. They’re split into categories, so you’ll know where to add new properties from plugins.

**Side Effects (triggers effects outside the component)**

```
el
```

**Global Awareness (requires knowledge beyond the component)**

```
name
parent
```

**Component Type (changes the type of the component)**

```
functional
```

**Template Modifiers (changes the way templates are compiled)**

```
delimiters
comments
```

**Template Dependencies (assets used in the template)**

```
components
directives
filters
```

**Composition (merges properties into the options)**

```
extends
mixins
```

**Interface (the interface to the component)**

```
inheritAttrs
model
props/propsData
```

**Local State (local reactive properties)**

```
data
computed
```

**Events (callbacks triggered by reactive events)**

```
watch
Lifecycle Events (in the order they are called)
beforeCreate
created
beforeMount
mounted
beforeUpdate
updated
activated
deactivated
beforeDestroy
destroyed
```

**Non-Reactive Properties (instance properties independent of the reactivity system)**

```
methods
```

**Rendering (the declarative description of the component output)**

```
template/render
renderError
```

For more recommended `style-guide` of `Vue` - Look here [vue-style-guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-instance-options-order-recommended)

Comment: I suggest to use eslint-plugin-vue for your project it designed as per `vue` official guide - very helpful- Your welcome

Comment: Please could some one give example of this approach, because I berrely understand what this thing mean(How should it looks like in component itself and then I use it).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. 100% personal preference. I like to start with the data, methods and usually end with the lifecycle methods. That is similar to how it is usually positioned in the docs and seems convenient because data and methods get changed a lot, and lifecycle methods not so much. However, there is no reason to do it like that from the framework. Go your game.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to maintain the order of object keys in practice in JavaScript, but this [isn't guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties) for ES5 specification, which is supported by Vue. So it shouldn't be expected that the framework will rely on the order in which component properties are defined.

Component functions *can* maintain a certain order for consistency like other answers explains, but they *should not*. This is purely a matter of style.